# Random forest regression approach

Tags: regression, random-forest, genetics

I'd like to use random forest regression (in R, `randomForest` package) to say something about the importance of a set of genes (binary) for schizophrenia-related behavior (continuous measure). I am still reading up on this technique, but would already really appreciate any feedback on some questions.

- In general, is it a good approach to enter a few dozen binary predictors to assess their importance (as a set, and individually) for a continuous measure with a sample size of ~1000 people?

More specific questions:

- What are important considerations for deciding the number of genes to look at a priori?
- I have an additional interest in interactions (though perhaps not the most appropriate word in this context), does it make any sense to say something about the influence one predictor has over others by looking at the change in estimated importance of the others when that predictor is removed from the model?
- I have a few siblings in the sample, i.e. non-independence of the data, is this a problem with this technique and if so, is there anything I can do about it?
- The few papers I have seen so far on using this technique in a similar situation do not include any pretty standard covariates such as age and gender, should I?

Comment: In my experience, it is better to "put all options in at the start" and let the algorithm "sort it out".  Something like randomForest doesn't explicitly do interactions, but you can make interaction columns as explicit variables.  You could transpose your data to determine if sibling-ness is relevant.  See the first answer.

Comment: Thanks! Though could you explain your suggestion to 'transpose the data' and what that would indicate a bit more? I don't see the first answer you're referring to.

Comment: I think of variables as columns, and samples as rows.  If you were measuring 1000 positions in x, y, and z, then your data would be 1000 rows and 3 columns.  You have a situation that is more like 3 measurements in 1000 columns.  The goal is to reduce the columns without loss of information.  I would treat the humans as your "dimension", and the presence or absence of a gene as  a sample.  You can use something like Boruta to get to fewer "columns" by removing redundant or non-informative ones.  When you are done you will have a reduced set of Genes to look at

Comment: I guess there is a bit of a misunderstanding (or I'm just not getting how this would work); with siblings I mean there are brothers and sisters in the sample, I don't want to reduce the number of genes to look at (well, perhaps later on, but I would then use standard variable selection procedures). Or do you mean that I would use Boruta to select only the  'most informative' sibling?? Thanks for your efforts in any case and please let me know if I misunderstood.